# Systemwide Alarm?

Tags: linux, console

When I am on a console-only machine, I often find myself knee-deep in `screen`.  But, I would like to make an `alarm` call to get me off to my day job.

Is there a utility or command of some kind that will take over any console screen long enough to warn me of the time?

I don't have any sound.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

wall(1) does that. It's had some issues working with screen (1) in the past,  but last time I tried it they were fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Myself, I like to rely on an external device for the time when working solely from a console screen.

My cell phone with an alarm set (even just on vibrate) works well enough.